# How to connect firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am new to firebase and I am trying to use firestore to get data for my next.js app but get an error.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  }
}
```

and here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import {
  getFirestore, collection, getDocs
} from 'firebase/firestore'




const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: "social-app-a0aef.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "social-app-a0aef",
    storageBucket: "social-app-a0aef.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "106093296170",
    appId: "1:106093296170:web:852948bb8d8fd86ccfe153"
  };

// init firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// init services
const db = getFirestore(app)

// collection ref
const colRef = collection(db, "books")

// get collection data


async function Firebase() {

    try {
        const snapshot = await getDocs(colRef)
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("firebase error:", err)
    }

    

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}

export default Firebase
```

I checked the .env.local file, the database status, and tried to catch detailed error but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try `console.log("firebaseConfig is:", firebaseConfig)` just before your call to `initializeApp()` to ensure you are getting the config values from your `.env*` that you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSnapshot() function was in my client component so I moved that to the server because environment variables were not public (this was the thing that caused the error). In next.js, the environment variables should be like this:

NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY='...' to be accessible to the client if u want.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NextJS and try to initialize firebase on the client (which you should), you need to access the .env environment variables with a prefixed `NEXT_PUBLIC_` Tag.

Try hardcoding the Api Key in your config to test it out.

Comment: I tried to log the firebaseconfig variable to the console and api key appears so the problem is not realted to env variables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).